# Remove separator line of table view cell on storyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview

When I drag and drop a Table View Cell to my UITableView on storyboard, it looks like this:

[image]

I would like to remove the separator line, I try to find from attribute inspector to remove separator line:

[image]

But I can't find any option for that. Is there a way to remove separator line of a table view cell in storyboard? (I am using xcode 9.1)

Comment: You could always do that programmatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please select the TableView and not the tableView Cell in the storyboard. The option is there to set the separator style to none there.

Before Image

[image]

After Image

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: But I need the 1st cell separator line, and I am dealing with static table view, is it possible to keep the separator line only for the 1st cell?

Comment: Add a view of 1 point height at the bottom of the first cell and hide the seperator and set a view in the first cell.

Answer (score 0):

[Md. Ibrahim Hassan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5807290/md-ibrahim-hassan) answer work until Xcode 13. And if you need to add separator for some cell, I recommend to draw by using `UIView` with height 1px.